# 可変長引数テンプレートメンバ関数へのポインタ。その引数が期待通りにならない。

Tags: c++, c++11

以下のC++11のコードについて

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <typeinfo>

class foo
{
public:
    template<typename... types_>
    void method1(types_&&... args) {
        int status;

        auto method2_args = std::make_tuple(
                std::forward<types_>(args)...
        );
        auto fp = &foo::method2<int, int, decltype(method2_args)>;
        std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(method2_args).name(), 0, 0, &status) << std::endl;
        std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(fp).name(), 0, 0, &status) << std::endl;
//      (this ->*fp)(1, 2, method2_args); // error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::tuple<int, int, std::tuple<float, double> >&’ from expression of type ‘std::tuple<float, double>’
    }

    template<typename... types_>
    void method2(int a, int b, std::tuple<types_...> &args )
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.method1(1.0f, 2.0);
}
```

(this ->*fp)(1, 2, method2_args);がエラーとなってコンパイルできません。
コンパイラはg++-4.8です。g++-5.0, clang++-3.4でもエラーでした。

不思議に思い、エラー箇所をコメントアウトして、method2_argsとfpのtype_info::name()を表示させたところ

```
std::tuple<float, double>
void (foo::*)(int, int, std::tuple<int, int, std::tuple<float, double> >&)
```

でした。最初のがmethod2_argsで次がfpのtype_info::name()です。
method2_argsは期待どおりでした。
しかしfpは実に奇妙で期待していたものと違いました。

```
void (foo::*)(int, int, std::tuple<float, double> >&)
```

を期待していました。

- 質問１．
  fpはなぜこのような結果になるのでしょうか？
- 質問２．
  fpを私が期待したものにするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己回答です。
fpを

```
void (foo::*fp)(int, int, decltype(method2_args)&) = &foo::method2;
```

とすることで、期待通りになりました。

Comment: 回答の共有ありがとうございます。autoによる型推論がどこまでできるかというのがコンパラーのバージョンにより異なるということなんでしょうか。C++11の仕様的にはどのような動作になるべきなのかはわかりませんが、興味深い挙動の違いでした。

Comment: 何か根本的に勘違いをしていたようです。テンプレート関数の場合は、テンプレート引数を指定する場合一致した並びになっていなければならないのにそうなっていないために起きた問題のようです。
この場合はテンプレート引数を指定すべきではなかったようです。

テンプレート引数を指定するのをやめて、オーバーロードされた関数へのポインタ宣言する場合に立ち戻ったところ期待した結果になりました。

Comment: Apple LLVM 7.3.0の場合、Junichiさんが回答に示されたコードと私が追記に書いたコードとは同じ結果になるので、gcc(と古いclang)だけ`auto`の方が通らないのはコンパイラーの違いかなということで。とにかく`auto`絡みで期待した結果が得られない時には明示的に型宣言してみると言うのは覚えておいたほうがいい対処方法かもしれませんね。

Answer (score 1):

*fpはなぜこのような結果になるのでしょうか？*

- method2の引数`int a, int b,`は、型パラメータ`types_`を使用していませんから`auto fp = &foo::method2<int, int, decltype(method2_args)>;`のようにそれらに対応する`int, int,`を実型引数に与えてはいけません。
- `method2_args`のデータ型はすでに`std::tuple<float, double>`なのですから、そのデータ型を(method2の)`types_`に渡せば`std::tuple<types_...>`は当然tupleのtupleになります。

*fpを私が期待したものにするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？*
gccは手元にないので、Clangで確認しただけですが、次のように`fp`だけでなく`method2`も書き換える必要があるでしょう。

```
    template<typename... types_>
    void method1(types_&&... args) {
        int status;

        auto method2_args = std::make_tuple(
            std::forward<types_>(args)...
        );
        auto fp = &foo::method2<decltype(method2_args)>;
        std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(method2_args).name(), 0, 0, &status) << std::endl;
        std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(fp).name(), 0, 0, &status) << std::endl;
        (this ->*fp)(1, 2, method2_args);
    }

    template<typename arg_type>
    void method2(int a, int b, arg_type &args )
    {
    }
```

(追記)
`method2_args`の作り方を間違えると型の不整合が起こりますが、こうすればmethod2の書き換えは不要になりますね。

```
        auto fp = &foo::method2<types_...>;
```

(他は質問者さんのコードのまま。)

Comment: method2の実装は、都合により変更できません。という前提でお願いします。
というところで、追記でmethod2を変更しない回答をいただきましたが、
エラーとなります。
error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘&((foo*)this)->*method2<float, double>’

Comment: 手元のClangでは再現できませんので、そのエラーメッセージだけではこちらとしてはどうしようもないですね。

Comment: Apple LLVMのバージョン7.3がllvm.orgのどのバージョンに対応するのか、結局わかりませんでしたが、リリース時期から考えて3.8.0相当かと思います。よろしければそちらを入手して確認してみてください。